# Find the largest values on a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am working on a matrix in R, 230 x 230 and I want to extract the 10 (or any other number than 1) max inputs on the matrix, both their position and value.

The extra problem is that this is a similarity matrix, so I have 1s in the diagonal which of course I want to leave out of the max search.

Any ideas or commands for that?

Comment: your matrix is not square?

Comment: So sorry, yes it is, as it is a similarity. I had a typo..

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: you can use `which(mat > sort(mat[lower.tri(mat)], TRUE)[10], arr.ind = TRUE)` to get the the indices of the top 10.  Then, just ignore the ones where `row==col`

Comment: That can work, I'll try it. Richard it's a square similarity matrix, pretty straight forward I think, I just need the idea. Unfortunately I can provide my data in public. @bunk thanks, it worked fine.

Comment: oh, and probably add in an epsilon there so you dont miss the last one, `... > ... - 1e-10`.  Also, you could do a partial sort.

Comment: Thanks all, everything worked fine. @user20650 I will next time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A neat way to do this in general is with the underused `arrayInd` function, which gives you row and column positions for plain jane vector positions. That's how `which(..., arr.ind = TRUE)` does it. Here's how you might do it:

```
## creating a random 230x230 matrix
n <- 230;
set.seed(1);
m <- matrix(sample.int(100000, n*n, replace = TRUE), n, n);
diag(m) <- 1;

## function to return n largest values and position for matrix m
nlargest <- function(m, n, sim = TRUE) {
  mult <- 1;
  if (sim) mult <- 2;
  res <- order(m)[seq_len(n) * mult];
  pos <- arrayInd(res, dim(m), useNames = TRUE);
  list(values = m[res],
       position = pos)
}

diag(m) <- NA;
nlargest(m, 10);
# $values
# [1]  1  2 11 12 12 12 13 18 21 22
#
# $position
#      row col
# [1,]  59  95
# [2,] 178 202
# [3,] 160  34
# [4,]  83 151
# [5,] 150 194
# [6,]  18 225
# [7,]  13  38
# [8,] 206 182
# [9,]  89  22
#[10,] 142  99
```

Comment: great! A small detail is, as I have a similarity matrix, I get two times the 5 largest values `$values;
 [1] -0.5129030 -0.5129030 -0.4990625 -0.4990625 -0.4980365 -0.4980365 -0.4841525 -0.4841525;
 [9] -0.4825290 -0.4825290` and on positions something similar. i tried to alter it a bit: `nlargest <- function(m, n) {  ;
  res <- order(m)[seq_len(n)];  ;
  pos <- arrayInd(res, dim(m), useNames = TRUE);  ;
  values = m[res]  ;
  position = pos  ;
  list(unique(values),  ;
       unique(position))  ;
}`  but now I get the 5 first values. how did you determined the number of values returned (10) ?

Comment: just modified the result so that I think it does what you'd like if the matrix is a similarity matrix, doubles the index that selects the top n entries from `order`, so it selects 2, 4, 6, ... instead of 1, 2, 3 ... that's `seq_len(n) * mult`

Comment: Just FYI... as of today, you need to add the decreasing argument to make this work.  >> order(m, decreasing = TRUE)