# How to obtain the highest p-values of a matrix?

Tags: r

Under R, I developed the following script :

```
X = 1:3
Y = 1:2
Z = 1:4
nlargest <- function(m, n) { 
    res <- order(m)[seq_len(n)]
    pos <- arrayInd(res, dim(m), useNames = TRUE)  
    values = m[res]
    position = pos   
    list(unique(values),
    unique(position))  
}
m = do.call(expand.grid, lapply(list(X, Y , Z), unique))
    m
    ecart=as.matrix(dist(m, method = "euclidean", diag = TRUE, upper = FALSE, p = 2))
     
alpha=0.8
m=10
proba_matrix=alpha*exp(-ecart)
nlargest(proba_matrix, 10)
```

The function `nlargest` that I imported from another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544566/find-the-largest-values-on-a-matrix-in-r) doesn't extract the n-largest values of the matrix `proba_matrix` as expected.

**I'm searching for a way to obtain n highest values of any matrix with their associated positions.**

Example of expected results :

```
m <- matrix(seq(1,9,by=1),nrow=3,byrow=TRUE);
diag(m) <- 1;
m
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    1    6
[3,]    7    8    1

# I need to obtain :
nlargest(m,4)

$values
 [1]  4  6  7 8 

$position
      row col
 [1,]   2   1
 [2,]   2   3
 [3,]   3   1
 [4,]   3   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 2-D matrix you could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

nlargest <- function(m, n){
  
  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(as.vector(m), expand.grid(1:nrow(m), 1:ncol(m))))
  colnames(df) <- c("value", "row", "column")
  
  largest <- dplyr::distinct(df, value, .keep_all = T) %>% 
    dplyr::slice_max(order_by = value, n = n)
  
  l <- list(values = largest$value,
            position = largest[, c("row", "column")])
  
  return(l)
}
m <- matrix(c(9, seq(1,9,by=1)),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)

nlargest(m, 4)

$values
[1] 9 8 7 6

$position
  row column
1   1      1
2   2      4
3   2      3
4   2      2
```

Comment: is there an option for the p-highest distinct values because the matrix I'm working with contains redundant values ?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the function using `dplyr::distinct` and updated the example with a matrix with a repeated largest value. Which repeat would you want to keep though? What is the criteria? This keeps the first by column.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your precious help!